# Python Create different variable names and instances for the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm trying to create variable names such as:

```
event1
event2
event3
```

to name different instances of the same class.

I searched online, and a lot of people are suggesting dictionary. But as far as I know, dictionary only works for pairs. I want to name different instances of the same class, for example:

```
class Event:
  def __init__(self, description):
    self.__description = description

event1 = Event('This is event 1')
event2 = Event('This is event 2')
event3 = Event('This is event 3')
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?
Thanks in advance.

## Edit 1:

It appears my question was not clear enough.
I do not know how many instances are needed. I will read the length of a file (the number of lines in the file), and then create instances of the class.

## Edit 2:

I have multiple pieces of information to fill in the class. For example:

```
class Event:
  def __init__(self, name, description, value):
    self.__name = name
    self.__description = description
    self.__value = value

event1 = Event('This is event 1', 'Tom eats apple', '20')
event2 = Event('This is event 2', 'Jerry eats pie', '10')
#......
#(maybe 20 or more)
```

Comment: What's the problem? You mean you want to have more than 3 instances?

Comment: You solved your own problem. What do you want to do ?

Comment: Yes, much more than 3 instances. The design is to read a file, find out how long the file yes, and create as many instances of the class as needed.

Comment: Where does the value fed to each instance comes from? If it is a list, then you can just store your instances in a list.

Comment: I do not know how many instances there will be. Perhaps 10, perhaps 100. I want to generate as many variable names as needed.

Comment: threading perhaps?

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the new additions to your question.

Comment: Just put your Event instances into some kind of collection, like a list or dictionary. Having separate names for each one is a _bad_ idea.

Answer (score 2):

To create many instances dynamically, one solution would be using a dictionary like below:

```
class Event:
  def __init__(self, description):
    self.__description = description


events = {}

num_events = 5 # Or whatever

for i in range(num_events):
    events['event{}'.format(i + 1)] = Event('This is event {}'.format(i + 1))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> events
{'event4': <__main__.Event instance at 0x02F70E40>, 'event5': <__main__.Event instance at 0x02F70DF0>, 'event2': <__main__.Event instance at 0x02F70DA0>, 'event3': <__main__.Event
instance at 0x02F70D50>, 'event1': <__main__.Event instance at 0x02F70C60>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, description):
    self.__description = description
```

now we want to create `n` instances of this class, using entries obtained from multiple lists:

```
entries_a = ['input 1', 'input 2', 'input 3']
entries_b = ['something 1', 'something 2', 'something 3']
entries_c = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Here is how we combine all the entries (the must be of the same length).

```
entries = zip(entries_a, entries_b, entries_c)
```

Here is how we can create instances of that class for the `entries`:

```
instances =  [Event(val_a, val_b, val_c) for val_a, val_b, val_c in entries]
```

or using dictionary:

```
instances = {(val_a, val_b, val_c): Event(val_a, val_b, val_c) for item in entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list:

```py
class Event:
  def __init__(self, description):
    self.__description = description

event = []
event.append(Event('This is event 0'))
event.append(Event('This is event 1'))
event.append(Event('This is event 2'))
...
```

So you can store as many instances you want without having to know in advance how many.

The solution with dictionaries is similar:

```py
event = {}
event[1] = Event('This is event 1')
event[2] = Event('This is event 2')
event[3] = Event('This is event 3')
...
```

or

```py
event = {}
event['a'] = Event('This is event A')
event['b'] = Event('This is event B')
event['c'] = Event('This is event C')
...
```

Depends on how you want to identify them.

Comment: That's hardcoding the instances... they say the number of instances is unknown.

Comment: Ah, so a dictionary can also store class?

Comment: It works! I think the dictionary solution is the way to go, thanks a lot!

Comment: Pouria: We don't know whether the total number of instances is know at creation time. So I provided examples how to add instances to a list or dict. If the OP understands this s/he can use those principles in list/dict comprehension. SamTulster: Yes you can reference any variable in a list or dictionary. (Under *certain circumstances* you can even use them as a key.)

Comment: That is hardcoding materials - not a valid solution in programming. Also, dictionary keys must be immutable. You cannot  use mutable objects as dictionary key.

Comment: @Pouria Huh? Robin is using integers & strings as the keys, both of which are immutable .

Comment: Thanks Robin, I think is the best answer so far. I'm going with your solution =D

Comment: Under certain circumstances you can even use them as a key. You should really say you can only use them as a key if, and only if, they are immutable. I know integer and string values are immutable, what we do not know is whether or not they are repetitive in this case. You are trying to teach them some principle, without telling them the important side notes, that unlike a list, repetitive values used as dictionary keys induce an override, which may threaten the integrity of the data. So either don't attempt to teach, or if you do, do it comprehensively.

Comment: That's why I put it in parentheses and emphasized the *certain circumstances*. The comment was not supposed to be comprehensive. It was not part of this question. But since the OP was surprised that you can reference instances in dicts I wanted at least mention that they *can* used as key in principle. If he wanted to know more he could have asked for those circumstances.